# TSQL Distinct, and OrderBy and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement sample:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [CommentNdx]
      ,[CommentsText]
      ,[DateTimeAdded]
  FROM [dbo].[CommentTable]
ORDER BY [dbo].[CommentTable].DateTimeStart DESC
WHERE [CommentsText] = 'Hello World'
```

I keep getting the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`  I know the syntax is incorrect but I'm not sure how this should be formatted.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

My mistake, I meant date time start should be datetimeadded.  Corrected syntax.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [TestCommentNdx]
      ,[TestID]
      ,[CommentsText]
      ,[DateTimeAdded]
      ,[OperatorNdx]
  FROM [PTDB].[dbo].[TestsComments]
WHERE [TestID] = 1174411854
ORDER BY [PTDB].[dbo].[TestsComments].[DateTimeAdded] DESC
```

UPDATE 2:

Thanks much everyone, one last thing, would it make a difference if there were joins in the select statement?  I have a really long query with joins and when I try to use DISTINCT, I get `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: A quick glance at the **fabulous documentation** for the [SELECT statement on MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) would have revealed what Luke and Shark answered ... MSDN Books Online is your friend - consult it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The WHERE needs to come before the ORDER BY. Also, you won't be able to sort by DateTimeStart unless it's included in the SELECT statement.

Comment: +1 good catch on the `DateTimeStart` column.  I completely missed that.

Comment: @Shark So did I, first time round!

Comment: why cant he sort by DateTimeStart ? It is not a requirement that it is in the select statement unless you refer to it as a column number reference (order by 2)

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=SQL.90).aspx: The ORDER BY clause can include items that do not appear in the select list. However, if SELECT DISTINCT is specified... the sort columns must appear in the select list.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [CommentNdx] 
      ,[CommentsText] 
      ,[DateTimeAdded] 
  FROM [dbo].[CommentTable]  
WHERE [CommentsText] = 'Hello World' 
ORDER BY [dbo].[CommentTable].DateTimeStart DESC -- you can't do this
```

`ORDER BY` follows the `WHERE` clause.

EDIT: As per @LukeGirvin post, you can't sort by a column that isn't included in the `SELECT` clause.